# When a React context state updates does it force a rerender of the child components if its context is not being used?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Just asking before I actually dive into this as this will rewrite a bunch of navigation logic.

Can I have the following structure where I have a list screen and an edit screen as follows

```
<DataProvider>
  <Navigator>
    <Screen name="list" component={ComponentThatUseData} />
    <Screen name="list different layout" component={ComponentThatUseData} />
    <Screen name="list another different layout" component={ComponentThatUseData} />
    <Screen name="edit" component={ComponentThatDoesNotUseData}>
  </Navigator>
</DataProvider>
```

If `DataProvider` has a `useState` and I update that will it cause a re-rendeer of the edit screen even though the `useContext` is not invoked?  Since a re-render will cause my edit form to lose focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, based on what I understand on the React Documentation, one of the caveats of React Context is that when the state in the Context is updated, the children will be affected, I think it's because the Context Provider is still a React Component.

[React Context Caveat - Section](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats)